# PHP - Choose 3 random items in array and replace 3 items with those 3 random items

Tags: php, arrays

What's the best way to choose randomly choose 3 items out an array and 
use those three items to replace another 3 items in another array. I though about using

```
array_slice()
```

But im not sure. Also my second array will be different each time. I've just include example below:

```
$array1 = array('A','A','A','A','A');
$array2 = array('C','A','A','E','D');
for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++){


    $min = 0;
    $max = 4;
    $n = rand($min, $max);

    $array1[$n] = $array2[$n];
}
```

Comment: Please add an example from before and after you replaced the elements

Comment: You don't want to be manually setting a min and max size, that is rarely a good idea when it comes to dynamic content. Set the max size to the length of the element you are dealing with.

Comment: @Josh Stevenson Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will take 3 random elements from the first array, and replace 3 random items in the second array

```
<?php 

$array1 = array('A','A','A','A','A');
$array2 = array('C','A','A','E','D');

$max1 = count($array1);
$max2 = count($array2);



for($i=0;$i<3;$i++) {
    $n1 = rand(0, $max1);
    $n2 = rand(0, $max2);

    $array2[$n2] = $array1[$n1];
}
```